# How to Create Android Button Animation with Parallel to Card Swipe Animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-button

Currently I am Working with Swipe Card Library https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards and I want to add a button with animation (Zoom in & Zoom out) With parallel to card's left swipe and Right Swipe. Button Zoom-in Zoom-out should control with card swipe action. Any help for this.

Comment: If you can access the `MotionEvent` of card . This can be easy to do . You need to take the event and calculate the the Zoom threshold or alpha threshold  . It will lie between 1 and 0 . And then animate the view using `PropertyAnimator`.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at [This library](https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck) . Its also doing the same .